# List references to labels of figures and tables

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I have a large document with > 100 tables in the appendix and many references at various points in the document.

Is there a way to create a list of references in the sense of finding all `\ref{...}`s to tables and figures in the text.

**Example**:
Consider the folling document with two pages of text and a section where all the referenced tables are listed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{text}
blabla \ref{fo} blabla \ref{fi} blabla \ref{th}
\clearpage
blabla \ref{on} blabla \ref{tw}
\section{tables}
\begin{table}\caption{on}\label{on}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{tw}\label{tw}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{th}\label{th}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{fo}\label{fo}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{fi}\label{fi}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Now I'd like to have something like `\listofreferences` telling me that tables 4 5 and 3 were referenced on page 1 and tables 1 and 2 were referenced on page 2

Comment: I am not trying to list the tables and where they are, but the references!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

The code redefines `\ref` and grabs the label name, puts it in a `\seq` list and and grabs the page number of the current position where it appears, storing in a sequence as well. Those lists are then stored to the `.lor` file which is retrieved with `\listofreferences`.

The macro `\trackonlylabeltypes` stores the label types that should be tracked, e.g. `figure` or `table`, all others are ignored, unless `\nottrackallfalse` is used.

Please note that the code may fail since `\crtrefcounter` tries to determine the underlying counter using some heuristics. If unsure, use `\nottrackallfalse`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_label_names_seq 

\seq_new:N \g_trackonly_labeltype_seq 

\NewDocumentCommand{\trackonlylabeltypes}{+m}{%
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_trackonly_labeltype_seq {##1}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addlabelname}{+m}{%
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {
    \seq_if_in:NnF \g_label_names_seq {##1} {
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_label_names_seq {##1}
      \seq_new:c {g_label_ ##1 _seq }
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addlabelpos}{+m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:cx  {g_label_ #1 _seq } {\thepage}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addlistofrefentry}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_label_names_seq {
    \addtocontents{lor}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\cref*{##1} }{\seq_use:cn {g_label_ ##1 _seq } {,\space}}{}{}}
  }%
}  



\NewDocumentCommand{\CheckIfInTrackTypesT}{+m+m}{%
  \seq_if_in:NxT \g_trackonly_labeltype_seq { \crtrefcounter{#1}} {#2}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\NewDocumentCommand{\writelistofreferences}{}{%
  \addtocontents{lor}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Referenced Value}{Page(s)}{}{}\addvspace{15pt}\par}%
  % Loop through labels
  \addlistofrefentry%
}


\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofreferences}{}{%
  \clearpage
  \section*{List of reference positions}
  \@starttoc{lor}%
}

\newif\ifnottrackall
\nottrackalltrue


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro{\origref}{\ref}
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\ref}{s+m}{%
    % Check for label existence first
    \@ifundefined{r@#2}{%
    }{% Only add the label if the type is correct
      \ifnottrackall
      \CheckIfInTrackTypesT{#2}{%
        \addlabelname{#2}%
        \addlabelpos{#2}%
      }%
      \else
        \addlabelname{#2}%
        \addlabelpos{#2}%
      \fi
    }%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \origref*{#2}%
    }{%
      \origref{#2}%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
  \writelistofreferences
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\trackonlylabeltypes{figure,table,equation}
\tableofcontents
\listofreferences

\section{text} \label{Footext}
See \ref{einstein} 

\blindtext \ref{fo} blabla \ref{fi} blabla \ref{th} but \ref{Footext}
\clearpage
blabla \ref{on} blabla \ref{tw}


\begin{equation}
E = mc^{2} \label{einstein}
\end{equation}

\clearpage
\blindtext
\section{Normal section}


See \ref{on} too and \ref{fo}

\section{tables}
\begin{table}\caption{on}\label{on}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{tw}\label{tw}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{th}\label{th}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{fo}\label{fo}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{fi}\label{fi}\end{table}
\end{document}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if one could do this using float?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: What do you mean with `using float`?

Comment: \newfloat{references} and \captionof{references} could creates a \listof{references}.  The problem is creating a list of pages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: You can go ahead, but I don't want to add even more packages. The problem of storing the labels etc. still persists

Comment: It was just a passing thought.

Answer (score 1):

I modified Christan Hupfer's answer to also work with cleveref references and multiple ref's, e.g. `\Cref{table1,table2}`. I'm posting this as a separate answer, but it's 99% based on Christian's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro,xparse,hyperref,cleveref,crossreftools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_label_names_seq 
\seq_new:N \g_trackonly_labeltype_seq 

\NewDocumentCommand{\trackonlylabeltypes}{+m}{%
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_trackonly_labeltype_seq {##1}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addlabelname}{+m}{%
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {
    \seq_if_in:NnF \g_label_names_seq {##1} {
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_label_names_seq {##1}
      \seq_new:c {g_label_ ##1 _seq }
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addlabelpos}{+m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:cx  {g_label_ #1 _seq } {\thepage}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addlistofrefentry}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_label_names_seq {
    \addtocontents{lor}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\cref*{##1} }{\seq_use:cn {g_label_ ##1 _seq } {,\space}}{}{}}
  }%
}  

\NewDocumentCommand{\CheckIfInTrackTypesT}{+m+m}{%
  \seq_if_in:NxT \g_trackonly_labeltype_seq { \crtrefcounter{#1}} {#2}%
}
                
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolor}{+m}{%
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {%
        \ifnottrackall\CheckIfInTrackTypesT{##1}{\addlabelname{##1}\addlabelpos{##1}}\else\addlabelname{##1}\addlabelpos{##1}\fi%
    }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\writelistofreferences}{}{%
  \addtocontents{lor}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Referenced Value}{Page(s)}{}{}\addvspace{15pt}\par}%
  \addlistofrefentry%
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofreferences}{}{%
  \clearpage
  \section*{List of reference positions}
  \@starttoc{lor}%
}
\makeatother

\newif\ifnottrackall
\nottrackalltrue

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro{\origref}{\ref}
  \LetLtxMacro{\origcref}{\cref}
  \LetLtxMacro{\origCref}{\Cref}
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\ref}{s+m}{\addtolor{#2}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\origref*{#2}}{\origref{#2}}}
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\Cref}{s+m}{\addtolor{#2}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\origCref*{#2}}{\origCref{#2}}}
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\cref}{s+m}{\addtolor{#2}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\origcref*{#2}}{\origcref{#2}}}
}

\AtEndDocument{\writelistofreferences}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\trackonlylabeltypes{figure,table,equation}
\tableofcontents
\listofreferences

\section{text} \label{Footext}
See \ref{einstein} 

\blindtext \ref{fo} blabla \ref{fi} blabla \ref{th} but \ref{Footext}
\clearpage
blabla \ref{on} blabla \ref{tw}


\begin{equation}
E = mc^{2} \label{einstein}
\end{equation}

\clearpage
\blindtext
\section{Normal section}


See \Cref{on} too and \ref{fo}
    
    Both \Cref{si,se} 

\section{tables}
\begin{table}\caption{on}\label{on}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{tw}\label{tw}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{th}\label{th}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{fo}\label{fo}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{fi}\label{fi}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{si}\label{si}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{se}\label{se}\end{table}
\end{document}


\end{document}
```