# hyperref: list of places that linked to a label?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, loops

I'm using the `hyperref` package. I can link to labels with `\hyperref[tag1]{tag 1}`. 
I want to create a list that links to every "section" that included a link to the current section.
So it would look something like this:

[image: shows compiled latex]

I've created a test file thats shows roughly how I imagined it beeing implemented (below i listed the issues I faced):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor, hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor={red!50!black}, citecolor={blue!50!black}, urlcolor={blue!80!black}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\setlabel}[1]{\label{tag#1}
% create list labellist#1 
}

\newcommand{\link}[1]{\hyperref[tag#1]{Thing #1}
% t=get latest label that was set before this command was called
% add t to labellist#1 
}

\newcommand{\linkback}[1]{
% if labellist#1 != empty:
%   \begin{tiny}(
%   for each element x in labellist#1:
%       #name = split last numbers of name of x
%       \hyperref[x]{Tag #name}
%       break if last element
%       , 
%   )\end{tiny}
}

\begin{document}
    thing 1:\setlabel{1}\\
        some text\\
        %\linkback{Tag1} =
        \begin{tiny}(\hyperref[tag2]{Tag 2}, \hyperref[tag3]{Tag 3})\end{tiny}\\

    thing 2:\setlabel{2}\\
        more text and see \link{1} and \link{3}\\
        %\linkback{Tag2} = ""

    thing 3:\setlabel{3}\\
        even more text, read \link{1}\\
        %\linkback{Tag3} =
        \begin{tiny}(\hyperref[tag2]{Tag 2})\end{tiny}\\
\end{document}
```

However I did not know how to create the following:

1. create a list that contains labels and can be iterated over later on
2. get the last label that was set
3. slice the label name to get just the last letters (numbers)

If there is another better way to achieve this I would be happy to hear about it :)

Comment: Labels with numbers such as `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3` etc. are not recommended, since as soons as you change the order of some labeled entity the numbers don't match any longer. Also `tiny` is no environment. With `thing1 \label{tag1`} etc. you will get no correct labels, neither in numbering nor in hyper anchoring

Comment: See my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418102/list-references-to-labels-of-figures-and-tables) for a possible starter -- it is somewhat related

Comment: In my LaTeX file I have a command that uses a counter to set the tag. Thus when I add a labeled entity before it will automatically change all other numbers.

Comment: Yes, but it is your job to add some working code and pseudo code

Comment: I meant: No pseudo code, actually