# \label and \ref logger

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I'm writing my thesis and since I'm using many labels to reference, I thought it might help for me to log \label and \ref on a separate page of my thesis. This is for me to keep a good track of the labels I have created and where they appear either on what page of my pdf document or on what line in my source code.

exmple:

```
x=y*z\label{eq:x}

y=3+d\label{eq:y}

z=d\label{eq:z}
```

Now, on a separate page I want to see (maybe in a table, but not necessarily) the label and the locations (possibly multiple references from the same label) where it was referenced, like this:

```
eq:x, ref1=page1, ref2=page15

eq:y, ref1=page3

eq:z (no reference, since it hasn't been referenced yet)
```

Comment: Maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/listlbls does, what you want

Comment: Related: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418102/79060](List references to labels of figures and tables)